# How can i add scale, opacity and translateZ effect on this JS typing animation just like in second example from anime.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

**There is JS 1st typing animation:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-typing').click(function () {
    $('#caption').empty();
        type();
    });

    $('#test-erasing').click(function () {
        erase();
    });

    $('#test-erase-and-retype').click(function () {
        loop();
    });
});

const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const wait = 15;//set the waiting time between adding/removing caracters

async function type() {
    while(document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML.length < document.getElementById('qqq').innerHTML.length) {
        document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML += document.getElementById('qqq').innerHTML.charAt(document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML.length);
        await timer(wait);
    }
}

async function erase() {
    while(document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        await timer(wait);
    }
}

async function loop() {
    await erase();
    await type();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #caption {
        font-size: 35px;
        }
    </style>
    
    
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qqq">this is someone example sentences </div>

    
    <input type="button" id="test-typing" value=" Type" />
    <input type="button" id="test-erasing" value="Erase" />  
    <input type="button" id="test-erase-and-retype" value="Erase & Retype" /> 
<br><br>

<span id="caption">  </span>


  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**and This is 2nd text animation by anime.js:**

```js
// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml2');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml2 .letter',
    scale: [4,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 950,
    delay: (el, i) => 70*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

```css
.ml2 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.ml2 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="ml2">this is someone example sentences</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
```

---

Now my Query is that
i want to add

```
    scale: [4,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
```

on my 1st JS typing animation. that will give it a look like flying typing text animation.

Just Like in second anime.js text fly typing animation example.

But now you will think why am not use anime.js instead of 1st animation, But there is problem is that the 2nd anime.js text animation need to break whole sentences into every different letter. that i don't want.

then i need to apply these parameters  `scale: [4,1], opacity: [0,1], translateZ: 0,` on my 1st JS typing animation, How can i do that ?

i tried these codes  `scale: [4,1], opacity: [0,1], translateZ: 0,` to inserting in JS style but it doesn't work.

anybody mastermind can solve my issue.

Comment: Hi, is there a reason that you don't want to put each letter into a span? It's just rather difficult to think of a way of animating each 'flying' letter independently without that - unless you do each one one by one through Javascript at run time which is rather painstaking.